# How to contact Microsoft Access on server side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, ms-access, server, server-side

**I am using the Microsoft access database for the ASP.Net MVC Project. How do I set my connection string or web config for the server side.**

*This is my DataSource* :  `var connect = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source= C:\Users\Dogruyer_5\Desktop\test_aktarma1.mdb";`

and my Web.config :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="test_aktarmaConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\test_aktarma1.mdb" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: When I publish the site with FileZilla, the site does not see the database. i need to change my Microsoft Access DataSource according to the server .

Answer (score 0):

```
Source=C:\Users\Dogruyer_5\Desktop\test_aktarma1.mdb
```

Only that user has access to that folder.

You must use a folder with public access or access granted to the account of your project. Could be:

```
C:\Users\Public\SomeFolder
```